# Windows UWP Application does not find Vibration Device

Tags: windows, uwp, device, vibration

I tried to make my device vibrating using the Windows.Devices.Haptics class.

Unfortunately it does not return any vibration device. The value is always null, although my device has a vibrator.

I tried it with:

```
Windows.Devices.Haptics.VibrationAccessStatus vibState = await Windows.Devices.Haptics.VibrationDevice.RequestAccessAsync();
if (vibState == Windows.Devices.Haptics.VibrationAccessStatus.Allowed)
{
    Windows.Devices.Haptics.VibrationDevice vibrator = await Windows.Devices.Haptics.VibrationDevice.GetDefaultAsync();
}
```

The code enters the if sequence, as the access status is allowed, but vibrator is null.

I also tried with:

```
Windows.Devices.Haptics.VibrationAccessStatus vibState = await Windows.Devices.Haptics.VibrationDevice.RequestAccessAsync();
if (vibState == Windows.Devices.Haptics.VibrationAccessStatus.Allowed)
{
    IReadOnlyList<Windows.Devices.Haptics.VibrationDevice> devs = await Windows.Devices.Haptics.VibrationDevice.FindAllAsync();
}
```

as I thougth, there is no default vibrator requesting by GetDefaultAsync, but the list is empty.

I thought, there is a permission rule to enable the vibrator, but I tried with some of them without success. I also read some post and all of them say, there should be no permission rule allowed in the manifest.
So I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: Could you please tell me what device you used to test your project?

Comment: It's a Microsoft Surface 3

Comment: We are consulting other engineers for your question. There may be some delay.

Comment: Are you trying to make the Surface Pro 3 itself vibrate or an external device? If external, what is the device?

Comment: Same issue with XBox controller, although I can use it via `Windows.Gaming.Input.Gamepad` or `Windows.Gaming.Input.RawGameController`